Earthly buildkit always return i/o timeout when pulling "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"
I am new to Earthly and I am behind corporate firewall.
Trying to verify the installation of Earthly by running earthly github.com/earthly/hello-world+hello but it always return i/o timeout.
I believe proxy been configured properly in my environment since similar operation like docker pull, git clone etc are working in my platform.
I might be missing some configuration of Earthly, if any, please do let me know.
Been searching in the web for few days but cant get any clue
Logs
# earthly --verbose github.com/earthly/hello-world+hello
            frontend | Running command: docker info
            frontend | Running command: docker info --format={{.SecurityOptions}}
            frontend | Running command: docker info --format={{.DockerRootDir}}
            frontend | docker-shell frontend initialized.
 Init 
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

            frontend | Running command: docker container inspect earthly-buildkitd
           buildkitd | Found buildkit daemon as docker container (earthly-buildkitd)
            frontend | Running command: docker container inspect earthly-buildkitd
            frontend | Running command: docker image inspect docker.io/earthly/buildkitd:v0.8.10
            frontend | Running command: docker image inspect docker.io/earthly/buildkitd:v0.8.10
           buildkitd | Comparing running container "earthly-buildkitd" image ("sha256:4bf3b76a1a36ce41fb98df9c8f5145c6e805a70ab4fd8dbaf6f773ce2fe64773") with available image "docker.io/earthly/buildkitd:v0.8.10" ("sha256:4bf3b76a1a36ce41fb98df9c8f5145c6e805a70ab4fd8dbaf6f773ce2fe64773")
            frontend | Running command: docker container inspect earthly-buildkitd
           buildkitd | Settings hashes match ("e9fe7910efadcc66"), no restart required
           buildkitd | Version github.com/earthly/buildkit v0.8.10 594835b598b9140741472bd8f3524cb502aa49f8
           buildkitd | Platforms: linux/amd64 (native) linux/amd64/v2 linux/amd64/v3 linux/386
           buildkitd | Utilization: 0 other builds, 0/20 op load
           buildkitd | GC stats: 188 kB cache, avg GC duration 0s, all-time GC duration 0s, last GC duration 0s, last cleared 0 B

 Build 
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

      registry-proxy | Starting registry proxy on 127.0.0.1:42803
matched earthly reference github.com/earthly/hello-world with pre-configured catch-all (regex [^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)
failed to connect to ssh-agent (using ) due to dial unix: missing address; falling back to https
converted earthly reference github.com/earthly/hello-world to git url https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git
https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# | --> GIT CLONE https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git
            internal | --> docker-image://docker.io/alpine/git:v2.43.0
             ongoing | ongoing TODO
             ongoing | ongoing TODO
             ongoing | ongoing TODO
             ongoing | ongoing TODO
             ongoing | ongoing TODO
             ongoing | ongoing TODO
            internal | [----------] 100% docker-image://docker.io/alpine/git:v2.43.0

================================== ❌ FAILURE ===================================

https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# *failed* | Repeating the failure error...
https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# *failed* | --> GIT CLONE https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git
https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# *failed* | [no output]
https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# *failed* | ERROR
https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# *failed* | The internal command 'GIT CLONE https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git' failed: error fetching default branch for repository https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git:  signal: terminated
https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# *failed* |
https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git# *failed* | git ls-remote --symref https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git HEAD
earthfile2llb immediate error: resolve build context for target github.com/earthly/hello-world+hello: failed resolving git project [platform: linux/amd64]: read uname-m: DeadlineExceeded: failed to load cache key: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/alpine/git/manifests/v2.43.0": dial tcp 54.236.113.205:443: i/o timeout
earthfile2llb group error: <nil>
Error: build target: build main: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: resolve build context for target github.com/earthly/hello-world+hello: failed resolving git project [platform: linux/amd64]: read uname-m: DeadlineExceeded: failed to load cache key: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/alpine/git/manifests/v2.43.0": dial tcp 54.236.113.205:443: i/o timeout
️ Reuse cache between CI runs with Earthly Satellites! 2-20X faster than without cache. Generous free tier https://cloud.earthly.dev

